# Cloudwatch Custom Metrics units for "minutes"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I've been scouring different sources (Boto3 docs, AWS docs among others) and most only list a limited number of units as far as time goes. Seconds, Milliseconds, and Microseconds. Say I want to measure a metric in Minutes. How would I go about publishing a custom metric that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seconds, Microseconds and Milliseconds are the only supported time units: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_MetricDatum.html

If you want to graph your data using CloudWatch Dashboards, in Minutes, you could publish the data in Seconds and then use metric math to get the data in Minutes: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html

You give the metric id `m1` and then your expression would be `m1/60`.

You can also use metric math with GetMetricData API, in case you need raw values instead of a graph: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-metric-data.html